# Using ngFor in angular 2 and got unexpected tds elements

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to use *ngFor to loop through an array of objects like this :

```html
<tr *ngFor="let app of apps">
         <td>{{app.name}}<td>
          <td>{{app.login}}<td>
          <td>{{app.password}}<td>  
              
</tr>
```

when this code is excuted, i got the following code html that contain unexpected tds elements

```html
<tr _ngcontent-c0="">
         <td _ngcontent-c0="">g</td>
         <td _ngcontent-c0=""></td>//this one !!
          <td _ngcontent-c0="">f</td>
          <td _ngcontent-c0=""></td>//and this one !!
          <td _ngcontent-c0="">f</td>
          <td _ngcontent-c0=""></td>// and this one !!
          
      
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the only information you showed, I can only see the missing close tags for td's

```
<tr *ngFor="let app of apps">
         <td>{{app.name}}</td>
          <td>{{app.login}}</td>
          <td>{{app.password}}</td>  

</tr>
```